# How to debug a peer to peer monogame application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, p2p, monogame

I'm currently working on prototyping a peer to peer game using .NET, Monogame, and C# in Visual Studio 2017. I'm utilizing sockets as the means of communication. The goal is to have a decentralized network of nodes, but this brings up the issue on how to debug it efficiently

What I've tried so far

- Set the timeout really high and connect with puTTY. This works for somethings such as how it handles the initial connection and such, but fails to be feasible for realtime communication. The other problem is that **the nodes utilize ECDSA** as a means of indirect security.
- Trying to google for solutions. This hasn't helped much as I have no idea what search terms to use.
- I have a decently spec'd spare computer that I just freshly installed Windows 10 on. but haven't done anything to it yet. Preferably I'd be able to run an instance of the client on each computer and use Python, Wireshark, etc to debug and automate the process.

Is there anyway to accomplish this in Visual Studio? If not are there tools for doing so? If all else fails what are some tools I could use to automate this process (Python, Auto Hot Key, etc).

The developers of something like Bittorrent would likely have to deal with the same issue and almost certainty have a solution to simulating several nodes either in software or hardware.

Comment: Your question is very general. Do simple logfiles, where you print all send and received bytes/chars, fit for this? With syncronized time.

Comment: Is there a way I can run freshly compiled code on two separate computers without having it transfer the client executable?